# Javascript how to change href

Tags: javascript

```
function PressMe(){   
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
         elements[i].href = "#HTML";    
    }   
}
```

Trying to create a function with plain JavaScript that should do the following but I am missing something and I am not sure what.

```
<li class="navigation">HTML</li>
```

Should be changed into

```
<li class="navigation><a href="#HTML">HTML</a></li>
```

For three list elements.

Have managed to do with jQuery but need it in JavaScript.

```
{
    $(".navigation").wrapInner("<a href='#HTML'></a>");
});
```

Comment: Well, you don't have a elements, so there is no href property which you targetting in your loop. Change innerHTML of li elements.

Comment: So copy the innerHTML, remove the contents, append an anchor, set the anchor's html to the innerHTML you copied....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :** You're trying to set the href to the li `.navigation` directly when you do `elements[i].href = "#HTML"`.

**Suggested solution:** Get the text of every li `.nvigation` element then create the new anchor with `href` contain this text then append it to the `li` using `.innerHTML` :

```
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    var text = elements[i].innerText;
    elements[i].innerHTML = "<a href='#"+text+"'>"+text+"</a>";    
}
```

Hope this helps.

```js
function PressMe() 
{   
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) 
  {
    var text = elements[i].innerText;
    
    elements[i].innerHTML = "<a href='#"+text+"'>"+text+"</a>";    
  }   
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="navigation">HTML</li> 
  <li class="navigation">TEST</li> 
  <li class="navigation">TEXT</li>
</ul>

<button type='button' onclick='PressMe()'>Press Me </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function PressMe() {   
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation");

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    
    link.href = "#" + elements[i].innerText;
    link.innerText = elements[i].innerText;

    elements[i].innerText = ""; 
    elements[i].appendChild(link);
  }   
} 

PressMe();
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="navigation">HTML</li> 
  <li class="navigation">CSS</li> 
  <li class="navigation">JAVASCRIPT</li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: It's good solution as it doesn't rely on `.innerHTML` property, which can be potentially exposed to XSS attack if text is user-generated.

Answer (score 0):

So select the text of the element, and add the anchor

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var html = elements[i].innerHTML
  elements[i].innerHTML = '<a href="#' + html + '">' + html + '</a>';
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="navigation">HTML</li>
  <li class="navigation">FOO</li>
  <li class="navigation">BAR</li>
  <li class="navigation">WORLD</li>
</ul>
```

or you can use createElement and append it to the li.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var li = elements[i];
  var html = li.innerHTML;
  li.innerHTML = "";
  var anchor = document.createElement("a");
  anchor.innerHTML = html;
  anchor.href = "#" + html;
  li.appendChild(anchor);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="navigation">HTML</li>
  <li class="navigation">FOO</li>
  <li class="navigation">BAR</li>
  <li class="navigation">WORLD</li>
</ul>
```